# Why wont this loop end? I've looked at it for ages and can't find the problem

Tags: c#, .net

```
Console.Write("Enter a string to encode: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
Random r = new Random();
char[] characters = " ~!@#$%^&*()_+=-0987654321`{}|\\][\"';:/?.>,<QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm".ToCharArray();
string method = "";
bool f = true;
while (method.Length != characters.Length)
{
    string cc = "";
    while (method.Contains(cc) || f)
    {
        cc = characters[r.Next(0, characters.Length - 1)].ToString();
        f = false;
        // Console.WriteLine(method.Length);
        // Console.WriteLine(characters.Length);
    }
    method = method + cc;
}
```

I'm trying to make `method`'s value a randomized version of the `characters` array.
I've looked at this for a while and I haven't found the problem.
Compiling the code and printing the length of the two variables shows that `method` is always 1 less character than `characters`'s length
It might be obvious to some, although I'm absolutely scrambled.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Search Stack Overflow for _Shuffle Algorithm_, you'll likely be happier with the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter of `Random.Next` is an **exclusive** upper bound. You need this:

```
cc = characters[r.Next(0, characters.Length)].ToString();
```

Now, just as a side-note, to create a string that is a random shuffle of the array `characters` you can do it this way:

```
string method = new string(characters.OrderBy(_ => r.Next()).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

As [enigmativity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67528052/624988) points out the second argument of `Random.Next` is an **exclusive** upper bound, meaning the function `Random.Next(0, N)` will return a value between 0 and N-1.

Therefore, after numerous random samples your code will eventually be set to `method` to contain all characters except `m` because `m` is the `char` at index `characters.length-1`.

To accomplish your task:

1. Change `cc = characters[r.Next(0, characters.Length - 1)].ToString();` to `cc = characters[r.Next(0, characters.Length)].ToString();`
2. Also, note that as you have fewer and fewer characters left that you have not yet chose, you will be picking many random characters you have already chose which is inefficient. Worse, the algorithm runs an outer loop which requires an array search to see if you have already chosen the character. This repeats until by random chance a character is selected that has not been chosen.

To address the issues in 2), simply keep a list of unused characters. As you randomly select each characters remove it from the list of unused characters. This will allow your algorithm to complete in 0(N) time where N is the length of total characters.

Here is example code:

```cs
Console.Write("Enter a string to encode: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
Random r = new Random();
char[] characters = " ~!@#$%^&*()_+=-0987654321`{}|\\][\"';:/?.>,<QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm".ToCharArray();
string method = "";
bool f = true;
var unused = characters.ToList();
while (method.Length != characters.Length)
{
    char cc = unused[r.Next(0, unused.Count)];
    method = method + cc;
    unused.Remove(cc);
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/users/259769/enigmativity